# Execute UpdateAsync and DeleteAsync with WHERE clause in SQLite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, asynchronous, sqlite-net

I'm using the following Library in my project: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net
I looked through the documentation and I couldn't find a way of doing `UpdateAsync` or `DeleteAsync` with a `WHERE` clause. For example, in a Get method it looks like this:

```
await sqlConnection.Table<MyTable>().Where(v => v.Type.Equals(type)).ToListAsync().ContinueWith((t) => { ... }
```

However, with the `UpdateAsync` or `DeleteAsync` the Where method is not there. So far I've been using the Query and constructing the query by hand, but this is kind of pointless since I'm using an ORM for this purpose, and I'm talking about something as simple as an Update or Delete command. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
var ExistingUser = await db.FindAsync<User>(u => u.UserName == user.UserName);
if (ExistingUser != null)
{
    await db.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

(Where UserName is the Primary Key of my User table.)